# AlertDialog.Builder does not show ArrayList<String> as list

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to develop an app, where you speak a name and it will lookup your contacts and return all names like "Lars A., Lars B., Lars C.". I save all those names in an ArrayList and it works.
Now I want to have a AlertDialog, so the User can select the right contact out of this list. I  figured out, that it has to be a CharSequence, so I convert it before. But I think the list is empty, because I only see the alert message.

This site describes it very well, but uses static values, I need dynamic values: [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Heres my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 CharSequence[] cs = namearray.toArray(new CharSequence[namearray.size()]);
 builder.setMessage("Welche/n " + cname + " meinst du?");
 builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
 int item) {
 //do something
 }   });
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

Comment: Use a debugger, or traces in the code, to see if and why the list is empty. Then fix the bug.

Comment: when I do cs.toString(); it returns: Java_Lang_CharSequence@.... and no list

Comment: To get a meaningful String representation of an array, use `Arrays.toString(cs)`.

Comment: ohh ok this worked, i guess the list is not empty then. but that means something has to be wrong with alertdialog or setItems? But why is it showing the Message and not the items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Because the list appears in the dialog's content area, the dialog cannot show both a message and a list and you should set a title for the dialog with setTitle().

Comment: omg thank you so much, this small mistake took so much time :(